# Get google sheet authentication by Replit env variables: key error

Tags: python, replit, pygsheets

I am try to get google sheet api authentication using pygsheets in the Replit. I saved the credentials json content into the "Secrets" function of Replit, the code is as below:

```
import pygsheets
import os
import json

creds = json.loads(os.environ.get('GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS'))
with open('gcreds.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(creds, fp)
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_env_var = 'gcreds.json')
```

The 'GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS' is a below when i open the raw editor of Secrets:

```
"GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS": "{\"type\": \"service_account\", \"project_id\": \"xxx\", \"private_key_id\": \"xxx\", \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nxxx\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\", \"client_email\": \"xxx\", \"client_id\": \"xxx\", \"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\", \"token_uri\": \"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\", \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\", \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com\"}"
```

After running the .py file it gives me a **KeyError: 'gcreds.json'**

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual environment, what is `gcreds.json` of `gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_env_var = 'gcreds.json')`? For example, in your script, is that `gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_env_var = 'GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS')`? [Ref](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/authorization.html#environment-variables)

Comment: I am using the Replit environment, since i need to key my keys private so i keep them in the Secret function there, which need to be called by `os.environ.get` to get the keys

Comment: but you have reminded me, i have changed the `gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_env_var = 'gcreds.json')` to `gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file= 'gcreds.json')`, there is no error now, let me do some work in that to see if this work, thanks!

Comment: I found that your solution works, and my "solution" defeated my security purpose, thanks a lot!